# Suite CRM REST API set_entry for Account

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am trying to create Account in Suite CRM using REST API, here below is my json data for Accounts.

> {"method":"set_entry","input_type":"json","response_type":"json","rest_data":"{\"session\":\"3af90fbac39a67110d025925189f960f\",\"module_name\":\"Accounts\",\"name_value_list\":{\"name\":\"Spotsmeyer's Furnishings\",\"date_entered\":null,\"date_modified\":null,\"modified_user_id\":null,\"created_by\":\"Administrator\",\"description\":\"Spotsmeyer's Furnishings\",\"deleted\":\"false\",\"assigned_user_id\":null,\"account_type\":\"Customer\",\"industry\":null,\"annual_revenue\":null,\"phone_fax\":null,\"billing_address_street\":\"612 South Sunset Drive\",\"billing_address_city\":\"Miami\",\"billing_address_state\":null,\"billing_address_postalcode\":\"37125\",\"billing_address_country\":\"US\",\"rating\":null,\"phone_office\":null,\"phone_alternate\":null,\"website\":null,\"ownership\":null,\"employees\":null,\"ticker_symbol\":null,\"shipping_address_street\":\"2 Lewes Road\",\"shipping_address_city\":\"Dudley\",\"shipping_address_state\":null,\"shipping_address_postalcode\":\"GB-DY5 4DJ\",\"shipping_address_country\":null,\"parent_id\":null,\"sic_code\":null,\"campaign_id\":null,\"email\":[{\"email_address\":\"spotsmeyers.furnishings@cronuscorp.net\"}]}}"}

Here in email node API accept array of email_address as per documentation. But I am getting error and it's not creating account in CRM.
Error is:

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /var/www/vhosts/templatebar.com/httpdocs/Individual/abhishek/suitecrm1/service/v3_1/SugarWebServiceImplv3_1.php on line *248*

I have checked the SugarWebServiceImplv3_1.php file in line 248. Like

> $seed->{$value['name']} = $value['value'];

But when I remove the email node from the json packet, set_entry API successfully create an Account in CRM and return the valid response.

I shall be grateful for any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it will give you error.

As per 7.7 Enterprise version in account module , you can add more that one email address as per Default functionality of the account module.

Here Field name for Email address is **email** not **email address**

I think this is the problem otherwise API wil work.

Comment: Thanks Amitesh for your quick and valuable response. I have renamed the only email in packet for email and removed email_address, now it successfully creating account without any error. But still it has some problem as it's not showing any email for corresponding Account in CRM, but in response of set_entry API I can see it's returning email id. Can you please tell me where I am missing something.

Comment: if this solve your problem kindly upload and accept the answer.

Comment: you should use loop to get emails

Comment: Field Name email1, when I set email id in this field it perfectly working.